# send 1 million messages to queue in 1 minutes

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, python-multiprocessing, pika

I am using rabbitMQ to receive the message.
I have 1,000,000 messages need to send out in 1 minute to queue. I am using multiprocessing by python.My code can send over 5 minute. Is that possible to send them in 1 minute in the single pc.
Here is my code

```
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime
import pika
import time
import uuid
import sys

class PyPikaTest:

def publish(self,no_message,producer):
    c = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(port=5672,virtual_host="test"))

    channel = c.channel()
    qname = str(uuid.uuid4())
    channel.queue_declare(queue='letterbox')

    print("start: %s" % (time.ctime(time.time())))

    for i in range(1, int(no_message)):
        sendtime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-2]
        body = ('aa cccc ' + str(sendtime))
        _properties = pika.BasicProperties(
            content_type='application/json',
            content_encoding='utf-8',
            message_id=producer + "_message_no_" + str(i),
            timestamp=int(time.time())
        )

        channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='',
            routing_key='letterbox',
            properties=_properties,
            body=body
        )
    print("end: %s" % (time.ctime(time.time())))
    c.close()

def thread_publish(self, no_publisher, no_message):

    jobs = []
    for i in range(int(no_publisher)):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.publish,args=(no_message, "test_publisher_no_" + str(i)))
        jobs.append(process)
        #Start the threads (i.e. calculate the random number lists)
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

        #Ensure all of the threads have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print("List processing complete.")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('starting .. %s')
    x = PyPikaTest()
    x.thread_publish(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Faster CPU? Split across multiple processes?

Comment: I am using macpro 2018 core i5, I need multiple processes

Comment: You likely do. For what it's worth, machines in the 2020+ timeframe are significantly faster as both Intel and AMD made big breakthroughs around that timeframe, especially on single-core performance. If new hardware is an option, that may be part of the solution, but *parallel* code is going to be a key as well.

Comment: you mean, I need to upgrade the CPU that makes it run faster?

Comment: Try working with multiple processes first, as you may be utilizing only one thread out of 4+ on your CPU. In other words, split up your workload, then insert it in parallel. This of course assumes RabbitMQ isn't the bottleneck here. While it's fast, I'm not sure it can handle >250K messages per second except on high-end hardware. This may be a limitation of what your machine can do, as the i5, especially on laptops, is not always the best performing chip. It's not bad, but if you need absolute speed, an i7, i9, or AMD 7 or 9 series is worth considering if that's an option.

Comment: A queue in RabbitMQ will only use one processor, so consider using multiple queues. You may also want to consider a faster client library than Pika, or a different programming language. Finally, a [dedicated tool](https://perftest.rabbitmq.com/) exists to benchmark your environment - you should give that a try. If you need further assistance, use [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users) or [discussions](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions).

Comment: I tried with CPU 4 processor and 8 threads, it took 2 mins to send 1 millions messages to queue. I think if with CPU 16 threads , it will make faster. But I still have to optimize by code with multiple processes. I a using pika to easy modify and handle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of the pika non-blocking connections? I use the AsyncioConnection. When publishing only from a single Python process and I can get 14k-17k messages sent per second, which is about 1mm messages in a minute. This in on a 2018 MacBook Pro i7, RabbitMQ installed locally with Homebrew and Python 3.11.

I created a script where i could attain sending 1mm messages in 61 seconds by chunking it up into 10 batches of 100k asynchronous requests.

```py
    total_request_time = 0
    batch_size = 100000
    number_of_batches = 10
    for i in range(number_of_batches):
        rr_start_time = time.time()
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(send_message(client_api)) for _ in range(batch_size)]
        _ = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
        rr_taken = time.time() - rr_start_time
        total_request_time += rr_taken
        logger.info("batch %s of %s calls took %s seconds and %s calls/s", i, batch_size, rr_taken, batch_size / rr_taken)
```

For full disclosure I had 4 consumers running, I find that RabbitMQ works best when sending if the queue does not get too large.

The full example code [can be found here](https://github.com/robertbetts/nuropb/tree/main/examples/addhoc)

This is my program output.

```
I 2023-09-25 00:01:29,536 one_million_example       main                                 17  : Client connected
I 2023-09-25 00:01:35,772 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 0 of 100000 calls took 6.235662937164307 seconds and 16036.787268279675 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:01:41,478 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 1 of 100000 calls took 5.705104827880859 seconds and 17528.161710771692 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:01:47,438 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 2 of 100000 calls took 5.960079193115234 seconds and 16778.30054934751 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:01:53,282 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 3 of 100000 calls took 5.84413480758667 seconds and 17111.172704329678 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:01:59,617 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 4 of 100000 calls took 6.335207939147949 seconds and 15784.801534620101 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:02:05,506 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 5 of 100000 calls took 5.888730049133301 seconds and 16981.590116313437 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:02:12,120 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 6 of 100000 calls took 6.614094972610474 seconds and 15119.226502508423 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:02:18,071 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 7 of 100000 calls took 5.950514793395996 seconds and 16805.268698933756 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:02:24,473 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 8 of 100000 calls took 6.401550054550171 seconds and 15621.21660345697 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:02:30,549 one_million_example       main                                 41  : batch 9 of 100000 calls took 6.075830936431885 seconds and 16458.654140683902 calls/s
I 2023-09-25 00:02:30,549 one_million_example       main                                 44  : Request only performance: 1000000 total calls in 61.010910511016846 seconds @ 16390.511002444855 calls/s
```

Comment: thank you for your sharing, with my macbook 2018 core i5, it took 260 seconds to send all 1 mm. I will try to check it.